# Detecting if a type throws

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Is there a way to detect statically if a any member of a class can throw an exception? Some metaprogramming trick?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? If a member function throws? If the constructor throws? Both?

Comment: and do you mean if it *can* throw an exception? Or whether it actually does so for some given set of inputs? (Which would require solving the halting problem) (so would the former, unless you allow false positives)

Comment: ... and do you need to detect this statically (compile time) or dynamically (runtime)?

Comment: I believe he might mean something like Java exceptions(not RuntimeExceptions), which do not exist in C++.

Comment: No, there is no way. Now you need to not ask these "step" questions and ask about the real problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I think the OP got an unfair treatment here. His question seems perfectly clear to me: for a designated class, can any of its member functions possibly throw an exception? It has nothing to do with exception specifications. This question can be answered by inspecting the source code: enumerate the methods, check to see if the method code (or what it might call or inherit from) can throw an exception. Is this *easy* to do? No, but I think the issue could be answered by a tool that simply used the facts available form the source code. (I build tools that could collect this information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't (assuming you want to know that *method* throws an exception). Programmer may use "throw" keyword in method declaration but it is optional. So there aren't ways to know if a method throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ there is no equivalent of checked exceptions as there is in Java.
So it is not possible to know if a method throws any kind of exception unless it is documented or you know implementation details.
A method, for example, that operates only on build-in types is guaranteed not to throw any exceptions.
A method that has the empty throw specification in the declaration it "says" that it will only throw an exception for deadly errors

```
int foo() throw(); //does not mean it will never throw an exception
```

Even allocation via `new` operator may throw an exception.
It is the responsibility of the programmer to specify explicitly what no-throw guarantees his methods give.